# angular 4 hash url issue with routing

Tags: angular, url-rewriting

**I am not getting hash in my angular app for local site.**

my configurations are here.

> app-routing-module.ts

[image]

> app.module.ts

[image]

Now, if after this configurations, I think my site should take hash in url like

**http://localhost:4200/app#**

but it's not working.

can anyone help me with this?

Comment: http://localhost:4200/#app

Comment: it's not matter, I just want hash anywhere in url

Comment: Hi there, when I use # in the url it doesn't hit the component specified in the router file. Even I used useHash: true. Have you found a solution to your problem?

Answer (score 0):

In your app-routing-module.ts use

```
{ useHash: true}
```

You already exported RouterModule from app-routing-module.ts so you don't need to agian import in app.module.ts. So remove RouterModule and all related code from app.module.ts and just import app-routing-module.ts in app.module.ts.

Hope it will help.

Comment: thanks @sandip, I  got your point, but it's not working, I mean I am not able to add {useHash} key in app-routing-module file. can you give me code example or reference site, anything where this kind of code done in app-routing-module.ts file.